# Trying to recover/import/transfer database from MySQL data dir

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I used *phpMyAdmin->export* to create a backup of my database but I have now discovered it did not export the whole database, some tables was missed/refused.

However at the time of doing the export I also saved the whole *data* directory located at *mysql/data/* which has many **.ibd** and **.frm** filetypes, which seem to reflect the tables I used to have.

I have tried to copy the entire *data* directory and paste it into my new setup, but I am not sure if the versions of *MySQL* / *phpMyAdmin* are the same, how can I find the MySQL version from my old *data* directory? Possibly in one of those **.frm** / **.ibd** files?

When I do paste the entire *data* folder, some of the tables in the database are working like normal but some display the following error.

```
#1033 - Incorrect information in file: '.\db\a_table.frm'
```

Also it seems every table which shows this same error message is marked **in use** under **Collation** in the *Structure* view in *phpMyAdmin*

What can I do to fix this? What does it mean?

I am wondering if I re-create my old OS setup, it could work? 
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a workaround for this but I am not very happy about it.
I installed my previuos setup which was *EasyPHP* and copied my old *MySQL* *data* dir into the *EasyPHP* *MySQL* data directory.

This time around the database was able to read the **.ibd** / **.frm** files correctly.(even though these files did not change at all)

I then used *phpMyAdmin* to export the database(this time around all tables/data was stored in the sql file)

I then disabled **EasyPHP** enviroment and started up my new enviroment and used *phpMyAdmin->import* with the new sql file which loaded the data correctly.

Overall I think its pretty poor that **MySQL** cant simply output some type of notice stating that the *.ini* enviroment variables are not set corresponding to the **.ibd** / **.frm** files rather than just output *incorrect information* and leave the user in the dark with all sorts of angles to think about. After googling around it seems many people seem to believe that their data is corrupt when that's really not the case.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find the MySQL version from my old data directory?

```
$mysql> select version();
```

Before taking the backup, you should know few things:
1. Default storage engine: `select * from information_schema.engines where support='Default';`
If it is `InnoDB`. You should run

`show global variables like 'innodb_file_per_table';` and check the value. If it is `Off` - there is a single file for data and index. 
So, You can't copy by database by just copying the directory. Also, copying database by copying the directory is not recommended way.
There are two ways to export the backup.

**1st way:** The way through which you are taking the backup - using `phpmyadmin` or other `GUI tools`. Its easy if your Database size is less.

**2nd way:** Use commands to export and import the data. These commands (mysqldump for export and source for import) are inbuilt in MySQL. [This post](http://ursitesion.blogspot.com/2010/10/best-way-to-easily-import-heavy-amount.html) would be very useful for using commands either on terminal (Linux) or command prompt (windows). You would have a lot of flexibilities also when use these commands.

Before importing, please check the storage engines on the destination server. Use the first query I have written in this answer.